# How to use some providers with the same service?

Tags: c#, architecture, ioc-container

I register the Service & Provider with some IoC tool(e.g. StructreMap)

```
public interface IProvider
{
    void Load(int id);
}
public class Provider : IProvider
{
     public void Load(int id) {...} 
}
public interface IService
{
    void Load(int id);
}
public class Service : IService
{
    public Service(IProvider provider) { }
    public void Load(int id) { provider.Load(id); }
}
```

Now I have another provider

```
public class Provider2 : IProvider
{
    public void Load(int id) {...}
}
```

I want to register that provider(Provider2) and to get the instance of Service with Provider2 from IoC tool. The only way I can see to do this is to create Service2 that will inherit from IService2 and the last will inherit from IService. And now I can get instance of type IService2 that will initiate provider with Provider2.

```
public interface IService2 : IService
{ }
public class Service2 : IService2
{
    public Service2(IProvider2 provider) { }
    public void Load(int id) { provider.Load(id); }
}
```

My question is: for every new Provider I need to write new class for Service even if the functionality of the service should remain the same?

Comment: shouldn't it be `public Service2(IProvider provider) ` ?   and then what are you trying to achieve? Do you want two Services that have the same interface only different implementations -> different providers?

Comment: I want 2 services that have the same implementations but different providers implementation. Ones it will receive Provider and other time Provider2. BUT, I don't call it manually. I want service from IoC

Comment: I can't see the problem then. 
You have to have the second Service resolve the IProvider otherwise. Every IoC has an option to resolve an interface differently on some basis.  something like `YourIoc.Resolve<IProvider>(someParameter)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to do that.

I would advice you to implement an abstract factory pattern for selecting the right implementation of provider depending on the value know at runtime.

For an example please look here : http://alsagile.com/archive/2010/06/28/Abstract-Factory-and-IoC-Container-in-asp-net-MVC.aspx.

It's in MVC context but can be easily implemented in other scenarios.

**Example :**

Youd could register your service like this (pseudo code) :

```
x.For<IService>().Use<Service>();    
x.For<IProvider>().Use<Provider1>().Named("provider1");
x.For<IProvider>().Use<Provider2>().Named("provider2");
```

You need a way to inject the container in your Abstract factory. You could wrapp it for example like this:

```
public interface IProviderFactory
{    
    object GetInstance<IProvider>();    
    object GetNamedInstance<IProvider>(string key);
}
```

And the implementation :

```
public class ProviderFactory : IProviderFactory
{     
    private readonly Container _container     
    public ProviderFactory (Container container)     
    {          
        _container = container;     
    }     
    ...
}
```

And setup StructureMap to resolve dependencies to your abstract factory like that :

```
x.For<IProviderFactory>.Use(new ProviderFactory(this));
```

Then into your Service you should inject the provider factory like this

```
public class Service : IService
{
    private readonly IProviderFactory _providerFactory;

    public Service(IProviderFactory factory)
    {
        if (factory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("factory", "providerfactory cannot be null");
        _proiderFactory = factory;
    }

    public void Load(string providerName)
    {
      var provider = _providerFactory.GetNamedInstance(providerName);
      // do some operation on provider
    }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: I tried something like this                            `For<IService>().Use<Service>().Named("core");
 For<IProvider>().Use<Provider>().Named("core");
 For<IService>().Use<Service>().Named("gen");
 For<IProvider>().Use<Provider2>().Named("gen");`, but when I try to get Service by `var o = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IService>("core"); var o2 = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IService>("gen");` it alwasy instanciate IProvider with Provider2 for both cases, why?

Comment: you sould register only once a IServiceProvider mapping. I post some code